# How to change Button visibility in ListView for only one row

Tags: android, listview

I have implemented an instant messaging layout with a ListView with custom adapter. Every row shows a message and hour. The xml that implements a list item contains a Button (@+id/alert_button) with visibility gone and that button should become visible if the sending of the message goes wrong.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentWithBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/risponditore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="@color/bluScuro"/>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabellaMessaggioOra"
            android:layout_below="@+id/risponditore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/rigaMessaggio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:maxWidth="245dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/rigaOra"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity ="right">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ora"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/grigioScuro"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/alert_button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contentWithBackground"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/alert"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the adapter:

```
public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements 
StickyListHeadersAdapter {
private List<ChatMessage> lista_messaggi_chat;
private static final String DATE_FORMAT_ORA = "HH:mm";//formato h24
private static final String DATE_FORMAT_GIORNO = "dd";
private Context context;
private ViewHolder viewHolder;
//private boolean visibility;

public ViewHolder getViewHolder(){
    return viewHolder;
}

public ChatAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.lista_messaggi_chat = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lista_messaggi_chat.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lista_messaggi_chat.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    //Log.i(HoustonConstants.TAG,"ChatAdapter getView");
    //ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        //The view is not a recycled one: we have to inflate
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message,null);
        viewHolder = createViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        // View recycled !
        // no need to inflate
        // no need to findViews by id
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final ChatMessage messaggio_chat = (ChatMessage)getItem(position);

    if (messaggio_chat.isIncoming()) {
            viewHolder.risponditore.setText(messaggio_chat.getAuthor());
            viewHolder.risponditore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        viewHolder.risponditore.setText("");
        viewHolder.risponditore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    viewHolder.txtMessage.setText(messaggio_chat.getText());
    viewHolder.ora.setText(getTimeTextOra(messaggio_chat.getTime()));

    if(!messaggio_chat.isIncoming()
     && messaggio_chat == (ChatMessage)getItem(getCount()-1)
     && messaggio_chat.getAlertVisibility()){
        viewHolder.alertButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    return convertView;
}

public void add(ChatMessage message) {
    lista_messaggi_chat.add(message);
}

public void add(List<ChatMessage> messages) {
    Collections.sort(messages, new Comparator<ChatMessage>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ChatMessage lhs, ChatMessage rhs) {
            return lhs.getTime().compareTo(rhs.getTime());
        }
    });
    this.lista_messaggi_chat = messages;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtMessage;
    public RelativeLayout content;
    public RelativeLayout contentWithBG;
    public TextView ora;
    public TextView giorno;
    public RelativeLayout contenitoreGiorno;
    public TextView risponditore;
    public TableRow rigaOra;
    public TableLayout tabellaMessaggioOra;
    public Button alertButton;
    //public TextView alertMessage;
}

private ViewHolder createViewHolder(View v) {
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.txtMessage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    holder.content = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.content);
    holder.contentWithBG = (RelativeLayout) 
v.findViewById(R.id.contentWithBackground);
    holder.ora = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ora);
    holder.giorno = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.giorno);
    holder.contenitoreGiorno = (RelativeLayout) 
v.findViewById(R.id.contenitore_giorno);
    holder.risponditore = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.risponditore);
    holder.rigaOra = (TableRow) v.findViewById(R.id.rigaOra);
    holder.tabellaMessaggioOra = (TableLayout) 
v.findViewById(R.id.tabellaMessaggioOra);
    holder.alertButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.alert_button);
    //holder.alertMessage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.alert_msg);
    return holder;
}

}
```

In the adapter in getView the button should become visible only if the message is not icoming, if it is the last and if messaggio_chat.getAlertVisibility() returns true. I set it to true in the activity where I manage the sending error, I add the message to the list and the button is visible.

My problem is that the button becomes visible not only for the last message but randomly for other messages.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

**EDITED:**

To be more specific, the user can send more than one message and there can be more messages with error in sending, so I need to set visible the alert button in more rows. Then if user clicks on one alert button he can resend one message (this is not implemented yet but will be next).

Comment: Change the final int position to int position for getView() method.

Comment: @Ankita still have random alert buttons visible...Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ViewHolder pattern and view is actually recycled so you have to specify not just when it have to be visible but also when it have to be invisible.

```
if(!messaggio_chat.isIncoming()
 && messaggio_chat == (ChatMessage)getItem(getCount()-1)
 && messaggio_chat.getAlertVisibility()){
    viewHolder.alertButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    viewHolder.alertButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: I've tried and it works! Thank you very much djevtic